# String into Array having issues

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to take a string of coordinates and create any array out of it.

```
var points = [];

points[0] = [-122.349517923,47.975040441];
points[1] = [-122.349518007,47.975040609];
points[2] = [-122.349758148,47.975320816];
points[3] = [-122.349972725,47.975363731];
points[4] = [-122.350101471,47.975342274];
points[5] = [-122.351560593,47.974805832];
```

Here's what I currently have

```
var path = "-122.349517923,47.975040441 -122.349518007,47.975040609 -122.349758148,47.975320816 -122.349972725,47.975363731 -122.350101471,47.975342274 -122.351560593,47.974805832";
var points =[];
var patharray = path.split(' ');
for(i = 0; i < patharray.length; ++i) {
        points = [[patharray[i]]];            
        }    
    console.log(patharray);
    console.log(points[0]);
    console.log(points[1]);
    console.log(points[2]);
    console.log(points[3]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w45nfn01/217/

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: And this line: `points = [[patharray[i]]];` is rewriting the points array each time. To add a new point use `points.push(patharray[i]);`

Comment: Thanks Changed it around some as it doesn't need to be a function. Let me try the push.

Comment: Thanks so much. I told I was new to this. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first "split" is ok, but you then need to split again on ',', and convert string to numbers:

```
var path = "-122.349517923,47.975040441 -122.349518007,47.975040609 -122.349758148,47.975320816 -122.349972725,47.975363731 -122.350101471,47.975342274 -122.351560593,47.974805832";
var points = [];
var patharray = path.split(' ');
for(i = 0; i < patharray.length; ++i) {
    var strCoords = patharray[i].split(',');
    points.push(strCoords.map(function(s) { return +s; }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joel. Worked like a charm. Cristy's method worked also though.

Comment: Yes, but there's a difference: in one method you get points as strings, in the other you get them as numbers. Depending on your context, choose the right one! ;)